# Get value of table cell by button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table rendered by js

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Город</th>
        <th scope="col">Регион</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="cities" style="overflow: auto;"></tbody>
```

Here is code

```
function GetCity() {
let citiesurl = '/cities/index';
$.ajax({
    url: citiesurl,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#cities").empty();
        var list = data;
        for (var i = 0; i <= list.length - 1; i++) {
            var tableData = '<tr>' + '<td>' +
                (i + 1) +
                '</td>' +
                '<td class="cityId" style="display:none">' +
                list[i].Id +
                '</td>' +
                '<td > ' +
                list[i].Name +
                '</td>' +
                '<td > ' +
                list[i].RegionName +
                '</td>' +
                    '<td> ' +
                    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="DeleteCity()">' + 'Удалить' + '</button>' +
                    '</td>' +
                '</tr>';
            $('#cities').append(tableData);
        }
    }
})
```

}

I try to get value of `cityId` by button click.

Here is code

```
 let id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cityId').text();
```

But alert dhow me, that I get nothing.

Where is my error?

Comment: I don't see any related html.

Comment: Updated post@u_mulder

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why not add cityId as `data`-attribute of a button? Or if you use a function - pass it as argument. Also it is strange - why you use `onclick` if you use jquery? Bind event handler and forget about `onclick`.

Comment: How I can do this?@u_mulder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the context `this` which is not the clicked button.

**Adopt the [Event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) approach for elements dynamically created:**

```
$('#cities').on('click', 'button.btn', function() {...}
```

```js
$("#cities").empty();
var list = [{
  Id: 11,
  Name: "Name",
  RegionName: "RegionName"
}];

for (var i = 0; i <= list.length - 1; i++) {
  var tableData = '<tr>' + '<td>' +
    (i + 1) +
    '</td>' +
    '<td class="cityId" style="display:none">' +
    list[i].Id +
    '</td>' +
    '<td > ' +
    list[i].Name +
    '</td>' +
    '<td > ' +
    list[i].RegionName +
    '</td>' +
    '<td> ' +
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">' + 'Удалить' + '</button>' +
    '</td>' +
    '</tr>';
  $('#cities').append(tableData);
}

$('#cities').on('click', 'button.btn', function() {
  let id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.cityId').text();
  console.log(id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Город</th>
      <th scope="col">Регион</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="cities" style="overflow: auto;"></tbody>
```

### A better alternative is using the [data-attributes](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

```js
$("#cities").empty();
var list = [{
  Id: 11,
  Name: "Name",
  RegionName: "RegionName"
}];

for (var i = 0; i <= list.length - 1; i++) {
  var tableData = '<tr>' + '<td>' +
    (i + 1) +
    '</td>'  +
    '<td > ' +
    list[i].Name +
    '</td>' +
    '<td > ' +
    list[i].RegionName +
    '</td>' +
    '<td> ' +
    '<button data-city-id="'+list[i].Id+'" type="button" class="btn btn-info">' + 'Удалить' + '</button>' +
    '</td>' +
    '</tr>';
  $('#cities').append(tableData);
}

$('#cities').on('click', 'button.btn', function() {
  let id = $(this).data('city-id');
  console.log(id)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Город</th>
      <th scope="col">Регион</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="cities" style="overflow: auto;"></tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify you code the following way, using `jquery`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        console.log($(this).data('city-id'));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- // these are your buttons. -->
<button data-city-id="2">Delete</button>
<button data-city-id="3">Delete</button>
<button data-city-id="4">Delete</button>
```

You can generate buttons something like:

```
'<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-city-id="' + list[i].Id + '">' + 'Удалить' + '</button>'
```

Comment: Can I write `data-city-id` variable from call on rendering table?